# Filling a shape in html5 canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working with canvas. I have drawn a shape as like in screenshot, but if i try to fill it, it fill wrongly as shown in screenshot.

This is my code
[image]

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="650" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">

<script>
var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(81.75, 319.5);
ctx.arc(198, 319.5, 116.25, -3.140796326794897, 0.0007963267948964958, false);
ctx.lineTo(210.91666666666666,319.5);
ctx.moveTo(81.75, 319.5);  
ctx.arc(198, 319.5, 12.916666666666668, -3.140796326794897, 0.0007963267948964958, false);     

ctx.strokeStyle = "#00ff00";
ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
//ctx.fill();              - Here the problem is
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();


</script>
```

Please provide a solution to overcome this.
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp says: "Note: If the path is not closed, the fill() method will add a line from the last point to the startpoint of the path to close the path (like closePath()), and then fill the path."

Also, take a look at this tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-shape-fill/

Answer (score 0):

You can draw this shape simply by drawing an arc and fill it with shape.

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 // Variables store centre and radius of arc
  var x = 250;
  var y = 225;
  var radius =100;

 // define start and finish angle
  var startAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
  var endAngle = 2. * Math.PI;

 // set the direction to anticlockwise
  var counterClockwise = true;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
  context.lineWidth =150;


  context.strokeStyle = '#fa4b2a';
  context.stroke();
```

Comment: This works.. But If i wish to change the size of the smaller arc is it possible?? How can I do that?

Comment: I am also need to change the size of the inner arcs alone.In that case it is not possible with the above code :(

Comment: you can change it by updating the linewidth and radius.

Comment: nope.. In this one arc is based on the other.. But i have 2 various values for each arc.. This can't be achieved in it :(